# Problems with setting up a basic Ember app

Tags: ember.js

I am starting out with Ember. I installed as per the documentation. When I go to http://my-app:4200 I get 'My Application' to show. However, when I go to http://my-app:4200/boxes the view doesn't show the contents of the boxes.hbs template ("Hello there from the boxes template!") - any ideas why not (files below)?

app/router.js:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    import config from './config/environment';

    var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
      location: config.locationType
    });

    export default Ember.Router.extend().map(function(){

    });

    Router.map(function() {
      this.route('boxes', { path: '/boxes' });
    });
```

app/routes/application.js:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('title', "My Application");
  }
});
```

app/templates/application.hbs :

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<div class="main">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

app/templates/boxes.hbs :

```
<p>Hello there from the boxes template!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely that your location type is wrong. Look [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/specifying-the-location-api/) for the difference. Ember CLI defaults to `auto` for the routing setting, which usually falls back to hash-based routing as it's the most compatible across browsers. This means that Ember is expecting you to go to `#/boxes` not `/boxes`. So you can either put the hash in the URL when typing out the URL manually, or just change the `locationType` to `history` in your `config/environment.js` file. (Note that history-based routing doesn't work in IE <10.)

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it didn't work. I noticed that when I start my app ni terminal, an error "routes/application.js: line 1, col 16, 'Ember' is not defined." (?) I alos switched on "ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;" in the /config/environment.js file, and the message I get in my browser console is "Transitioned into 'index' - suggesting that it isn't finding any route to /boxes.

Comment: you need to import Ember in routes/application: `import Ember from 'ember'`